# Spring STS bundle can't trigger controller

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I tried to setup a simple spring web by using Spring Tools Suite, but i cant trigger the Controller class and i am not sure what's wrong, when i go http://localhost:8080/ , it is ok, means my server is started, but when i go http://localhost:8080/MVCTest/test12 , it shows page not found.

My pom.xml is alright, i just had all libraries there, and im trying to use class notation, not XML.

Setup

Server: Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2 [Started]

Log from console, it seems ok:

```
Jan 14, 2017 12:29:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1108 ms
Jan 14, 2017 12:29:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 875 ms
```

My Controller code:

```
package com.app1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping("/test12")
    public void test12()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>MVCTest</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app1.controller" />
```

[image]

Comment: See the console after typing the link ".../MVCTest/test12" in your browser. You must see 'Welcome' text.

Comment: yup i tried, no welcome message in console

Comment: Can i see your web.xml.?

Comment: i edited the question, please have a look, thanks, after i added the web.xml, it shows: HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Comment: Do you have servlet-context.xml in your project file ? could you please extend your src folder?

Comment: nope, i don't have, i re-uploaded screenshot of my project

Answer (score 0):

You do not have Spring Application Context definition file which is necessary .This file ensures the Spring container does component scanning, so that any code annotated with @Controller is automatically discovered.

Go through [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) link for details.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?Please let me know if you still have any problem i will try to find you a solution .

Comment: hi @Surace, sorry i was away, i added servlet-context.xml too, but it is not working, i re-edited the question, please have a look at my servlet-context

Comment: Add servlet-context.xml path in your web.xml .